# PoE+ HAT fan not working correctly on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, poe

So I bought a new Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) and the official PoE+ HAT.
It is running the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 21.04 Server, completely updated.

Controlling the PoE+ HAT-fan should/could be done through `/etc/firmware/config.txt`, which I did.
This does turn on the fan, but it looks like somehow only 2 of the 4 settings are respected at the moment.

First, I tried this setup:

```
# PoE Hat Fan Speeds #
dtoverlay=rpi-poe
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=60000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=65000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=70000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=75000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

With these settings, the fan turns on semi-fast every 30-ish seconds around 70 degrees and stops again when it's hitting 65. Then it takes the Pi some 30-ish seconds to just heat up back to 70 again and the cycle starts again, with the Pi always within 65 and 70 degrees.

Then I changes the settings to the following:

```
# PoE Hat Fan Speeds #
dtoverlay=rpi-poe
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=55000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=60000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=65000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=75000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

Now the same happens, but the Pi is constantly between 60 and 65 degrees. Here's a graphic of the above mentioned situations:

[image]

So it seems like the Pi is only respecting the `temp1` and `temp2` settings and is using only one speed setting to stay within that range. When it 'accidentally' drops below 60 and should be in the range between `temp0` and `temp1`, the fan does not switch to a lower RPM, but just stops.

Just to check I once set `temp3` to `50000` and then the fan does ramp up to it's full speed, so it does know how to use the different speeds.

I also tried changing them to `temp1`, `temp2`, `temp3` and `temp4` instead of starting with  `temp0`, but then `temp4` is ignored and `temp0` is replaced with the default setting 40 degrees, as expected.

So in short the PoE+ HAT fan is only working in the range between `temp1` and `temp2` and not below.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find the other answer that I found that solved this, but I closed the window...but here's the nutshell of the answer: change `rpi-poe` to `rpi-poe-plus`

I ended up with, reboot and fan is spinning.

```
# POE Fan
dtoverlay=rpi-poe-plus
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=80000,poe_fan_temp0_hyst=2000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=70000,poe_fan_temp1_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=65000,poe_fan_temp2_hyst=3000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=60000,poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

the other bit from the answer was confirming that you have the "-plus" with

`ls /boot/firmware/overlays | grep poe`

Comment: Wow. That's both so simple and stupid at the same time. It's working perfectly!

I have the temps the other way around though by the way. `temp0` is the lowest RPM so the I have set it to the lowest temp.